# Expanding matter from exploded asteroid

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, explosions

Suppose an asteroid explodes, into a spherically symmetrical cloud, of radius ***R***, mass ***M***, and surface receding velocity ***V*** (normal to the edge of the cloud), initially the density is radially uniform.

Can anything be explicitly stated with respect to the velocity profile with time, and the density profile? Although initially, the density profile is uniform, I suspect it is bound to change with time and result in a radially varying density profile.

I am unable to derive a relation between the velocity profile and the density profile at any time.

Also the max radius (radius when expansion ceases) according to me is independent of density and velocity profiles (initial or at any time t) and is
$$R_{MAX} =\frac{2GMR}{2GM-V^{2} R}$$

Which comes from writing force equations at the external differential shell by shell theorem since mass enclosed within is constant so these equations become easy to deal with.

I only seem to find information of a spherically symmetric collapse of such a cloud, and a wiki with blast wave dynamics which is mostly unrelated to my problem and the given conditions, so another supplement question would be, is such an explosion bound to ***pulsate*** with time.

This is beyond the scope of given textbook questions and hence was asked on stackexchange.

I have seen the already existing question similar to this but the answer there assumes uniform density rather than proving it. Homogeneity of the cloud is only given for t=0 and not guaranteed that it evolves that way with time.

[Speed of particles in an exploded asteroid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563841/speed-of-particles-in-an-exploded-asteroid)

edit: My attempts of assuming different velocity profiles for example quadratic result in the following integral where the density profile can be found via a cubic equation with non trivial roots

$$\frac{3}{2}\frac{M}{R_{o}^{3}}\int _{0}^{R_{o}} V( r,R_{o})^{2} r^{2} .dr\ -\frac{3}{5}\frac{GM^{2}}{R_{o}}=\ -\ G\left( 16\pi ^{2}\right)\int _{0}^{R_{max}}\left[\int _{0}^{r} \rho _{Rmax} .r^{2} .dr\right] \rho _{Rmax}.r.dr$$

where $V(r,R_{o})$ is the velocity profile when the radius is Ro i.e. at the initial condition and $_{Rmax}$ is the density profile when expansion ceases. The right-hand side of the above integral is the gravitational self-energy of the sphere at the end.

Additionally supplementary questions:

from the value of $$R_{MAX} =\frac{2GMR}{2GM-V^{2} R}$$

it's clear that since the radius is positive, the denominator should be positive, what happens when
$$\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{R}} < V$$
Where V is again the initial normal receding velocity of the outermost particles in the cloud. Does the cloud just end up expanding forever and never really end up in a static state.

Comment: Why do you think there is a max radius? Your hypotetic asteroid party happens in vacuum, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, but each shell encloses some mass within and as it expands the enclosed mass remains same regardless of density variation so there is a varying gravitational force acting on it, the outermost shell also has a force acting on it due to entire mass m enclosed within it, there comes a time that due to deceleration the shell will come to rest and so will the interior shells. I know that this happens for a certain limit of velocity of each shell which is less than escape velocity.

Comment: Not necessarily. The explosion may completely unbind the body.

Comment: Yeah thats what I said, only for a certain limit of velocity that is less than escape velocity.